# Finite notation for natural numbers in base $(a+\sqrt{b})/2$

Tags: number-theory

Natural numbers in base $10$ have a finite notation. But there are other bases of the form $\frac{a+\sqrt b}{2}$, where all natural numbers can be written in a finite notation. In base $\frac{5+\sqrt 17}{2}$ for example the decimal number $11$ would be written as $21.4$.

What is the condition for possible values $(a,b)$ so that natural numbers can be written in a finite notation ?

Comment: You may want to study this article: http://people.fjfi.cvut.cz/pelanedi/Publications/AmbrozArithmetics.pdf But beware, it's no easy reading.

Comment: Thank you! I was aware of this paper but hoped to get a somewhat easier approach.

Comment: You're considering exotic bases but don't specify what the *digits* are (again!).